# Links in Ramaze with a/r helpers

Tags: ruby, hyperlink, html-helper, ramaze

In ramaze (2009.06.04) the link helper has changed and I have some problems to use it. I want to create a link to the MainController -> test action

```
#{a('Testlink', r(:test))}
```

This works if the URL is not in a specific controller. If the user is in a other controller like http://site/othercontroller/testtwo, the Testlink are linked to http://site/othercontroller/test.

How can I set the link constant to http://site/test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Controller.a method, like `#{UsersController.a('Remove', :remove_target, tgt.id)}`

Answer (score 1):

Try #{a('Testlink', MainController.r(:test))}